# Find value in the same collection (nested finds)

Tags: mongodb, nested, find, match, lookup

I have collection animals, like this

```
const animal1 = {
    id: '001',
    name: "cat",
    num: '001',
    strength: 2,
    family: "felines",
    animalsRelated:[ 
        {
            "num" : "002",
            "name" : "Tiger"
        }, 
        {
            "num" : "003",
            "name" : "Lion"
        }
    ]
}

const animal2 = {
    id: "002",
    num: "002",
    name: "Tiger",
    strength: 4,
    family: "felines"
}

const animal3 = {
    id: "003",
    num: "003",
    name: "Lion",
    strength: 2,
    family: "felines"
}
```

I need to try only a query finding cat if any of their animal related have strenth more than 3. In that case the query will give us Cat, but in case animal 2 strength was 2 it wouldn't give us Cat, it would give us nothing.
Any idea? I've tried with match and lookup without success. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would be much easier if you could store all of the related data inside the `animalsRelated` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be the following

```
db.animals.aggregate([ 
  { $lookup: { 
      from: "animals", 
      localField: "animalsRelated.num", 
      foreignField: "num", 
      as: "animalsRelated" 
    } 
  }, 
  { $match: { "animalsRelated.strength": { $gt: 3 } } }
])
```

The idea is to use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to perform a join and hence "expand" the subdocuments into their full shape, and then use $match to enforce the constraint.